# How can I make Timer do different things based on how it was started

Tags: vb.net, timer

How can I make my Timer do different things depends on what activated it? I've tried using this code

```
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Timer1.Start
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseHover
    Timer1.Start
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick, Button2.MouseHover, Button1.MouseHover
    If sender Is Button1 Then
        a = a + 1
        TextBox1.Text = a
    End If

    If sender Is Button2 Then
        b = b + 1
        TextBox2.Text = b
    End If
End Sub
```

but Textbox just add 1 once. This means that the Timer just act one time not continuously like Timer usually do. So is there anything I do wrong there, or i can do something different?.

Comment: The sender will never be anything other than `Timer1` - thats "who" generates the event.  Set a flag in the different button clicks that you can evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibly simpler approach, would be to use the Timer.Tag property and use one handler for both buttons:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    Timer1.Tag = sender
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    a += 1
    If Timer1.Tag Is Button2 Then
        TextBox1.Text = a.ToString
    End If
    If Timer1.Tag Is Button1 Then
        TextBox2.Text = a.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Since Tag is already of type Object no external casting is needed.

I included the Start function, since I wasn't sure how you're initially starting the timer.  If you're doing in a different manner it can be left out of the button event handler

Comment: thanks it works, i didn't know that Tag can be used like that. Well, I change and remove some code. Like `a.ToString` to just `a`.

Comment: While vb.net does allow that, it is considered bad coding.  Consider in a large project it would be easy to forget whether `a` is an integer or a string.  It is a good habit to get into to always cast your variables to the appropriate type.  It may seem like extra work, but vb.net is doing that anyway.  As always, if your question gets answered please remember to mark the appropriate post as the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is value of this and this is not, generally speaking, something people do, but if you want to know which action activated timer you need to register it

```
Private  _timer As Timer
Private _activatingControl As Object

Private Sub ActivateTimer(c as Object)
    _activatingControl = c ' this is first
    _timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseHover
    ActivateTimer(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick, Button2.MouseHover, Button1.MouseHover
    . . . . . . 
    System.Diagnostics.WriteLine("timer was activated by" + _activatingControl.ToString())

    If DirectCast(_activatingControl, Control).Name = "Button1" Then 
        . . . .
    ElseIf DirectCast(_activatingControl, Control).Name = "Button2" Then
        . . . . 
    End If
End Sub
```

So, you will always need to activate timer via `ActivateTimer`. `Timer1_Tick(sender As Object` will always be Timer itself

Comment: The System.Windows.Forms.Timer is the correct timer to be using in this context as it runs on the UI thread. The System.Timers.Timer runs on a separate thread and requires the use of delegates to update the UI to avoid cross-thread exceptions.

Comment: @GuruJosh Yea, I was thinking that you would need to check `invokeRequired` to update controls. Ok then, I removed that recommendation just to make it easy on OP.

Answer (score 0):

I like tinstaafl's Tag property method. A similar approach would be to create a custom timer which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Timer and has a Button property which can be set in the button's MouseHover event handler.

The timer's Start method only needs to be called once so I moved this to the form's load event handler. I am not sure exactly what you are wanting to achieve. Depending on this, the timer's Start method could be left where it was in the button MouseHover event handler and Timer1.Stop could be called at the end of the timer's tick event handler. This would then increment the value of the counter (a) only once in response to each MouseHover event. Alternatively Timer1.Stop could be called in the buttons' MouseLeave events if you only wanted the counter to increment while the mouse is hovering over the buttons.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Class CustomTimer
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private m_myButton As Button

Public Property Button() As Button
    Get
        Return m_myButton
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Button)
        m_myButton = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class

Private WithEvents Timer1 As New CustomTimer
Private a As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 100
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover, Button2.MouseHover
  Timer1.Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  a += 1
  If Timer1.Button Is Button1 Then 
      TextBox1.Text = a.ToString
  ElseIf Timer1.Button Is Button2 Then 
      TextBox2.Text = a.ToString
  End If
End Sub

End Class
```